# Model with associations, 1 request fill 2 components best practice

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

What would be the best practice or design approach for the following scenario:

1. There is a json been returned from the server that has information about people and their addresses
2. I need to show a form with the general information of the person plus a list with every address.
3. In this list it is mandatory that each address is an item of the list because it will be multiselect true in order to do something else.

What I have done is:

a)define a model "Persona" with a hasMany relation to "Direccion"(spanish for address), my proxy is here in the model

b)define a model "Direccion"

c)define a list and try to play with the itemTpl config in order to display 1 address per itemList but so far I can only display all the addresses for a given person in the same itemList.
**Is there a way to achieve this ?**

**Is this approach good given this scenario?**

I was trying to do only 1 request and have only 1 store to fill out this 2 components but now I'm having doubts about it.

**So what would be the best design/practice given this scenario?**

**JSON response**

```
{
    "personas": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "nombre": "jon",
            "apellido": "caballero",
            "direcciones": [
                {
                    "direccionId": 1,
                    "calle": "fco villa",
                    "colonia": "barona"
                },
                {
                    "direccionId": 2,
                    "calle": "duraznos",
                    "colonia": "canutillo"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Models**

```
Ext.define('Associations.model.Direccion', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        idProperty: 'direccionId',
        fields: [
            { name: 'calle', type: 'auto' },
            { name: 'colonia', type: 'auto' }
        ]
    }
});




Ext.define('Associations.model.Persona', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    requires: ['Associations.model.Direccion'],
    config: {
        fields: [
        { name: 'nombre', type: 'auto' },
        { name: 'apellido', type: 'auto' },
        ],
        hasMany:[
        {
            foreignKey: 'direccionId',
            associationKey: 'direcciones',
            name: 'direcciones',
            model: 'Associations.model.Direccion'
        }

        ],
        proxy: {

            type:'ajax',
            url: 'data/respuesta.json',
            reader: {
                type:'json',
                rootProperty:'personas'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**Store**

```
Ext.define('Associations.store.Persona', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: [
        'Associations.model.Persona'
    ],
    config: {
        model: 'Associations.model.Persona',
        autoLoad: true
    }
});
```

**List**

```
Ext.define('Associations.view.PersonaList', {
    extend: 'Ext.List',
    xtype: 'personalist',
    config: {
        onItemDisclosure: true,
        emptyText: 'No se encontraron personas',
        store: 'Persona',
        padding: 10,
        margin: 10,
        itemTpl : [
         '<tpl for="direcciones">',
                    '<li>Colonia {colonia}</li>',
                    '<li>Calle {calle}</li>',
         '</tpl>',  
        ].join('')
    }

});
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do model.load() and the model has a hasMany relation to another model a store for the child objects is autogenerated therefore the best approach would be to load the model get the store of the child records and set it to the list.